# Is there any possible way to define same path multiple times with change in parameters?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I need to define a service that is used multiple times with change in parameters.I need to define this multiple times but whenever I define it second time it automatically overwrites the previous one.
Following is how I defined it.This is first definition:

```
  /sevice :
    post:
      summary: Service ABC
      description: |
        This service is used to get ABC.
      parameters:
        - name: XYZ
          in: query
          description: '8'
          required: true
          type: number
          format: integer
        - name: LMN
          in: query
          description: '2'
          required: true
          type: number
          format: integer
      tags:
        - ABC
      responses:
        '200':
          description: An array of products
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/ABC'
        default:
          description: Unexpected error
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
```

This is the second definition:

```
  /sevice :
    post:
      summary: Service ABC
      description: |
        This service is used to remove ABC.
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: jsonData
          description: Object that needs to be sended to the store.
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/PQR'
      tags:
        - ABC
      responses:
        '200':
          description: An array of products
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/LMN'
        default:
          description: Unexpected error
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
```

Is it possible to have same path appear more than once in one API spec?

Comment: It's not possible as of OpenAPI 2.0 and 3.0. Related feature requests in the OpenAPI Specification repository: [Support an operation to have multiple specifications per path (e.g. multiple POST operation per path)](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/182), [Querystring in Path Specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/164), [Accommodate legacy APIs by allowing query parameters in the path](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/123).

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. I tried to do that but it gives a duplication error when checking with [Swagger Editor](http://editor.swagger.io/#/), as my API is built on the Swagger definition. My suggestion is to append the path with a name for the purpose of that service, e.g. for definitions one /service/get or /service/delete.

Also, I see that your second definition is designed to delete a resource and your first is to obtain a resource. You can the second one a DELETE HTTP method and the first one a GET HTTP method and combine the two definitions together. This way, your path is the same and can execute different HTTP functions. [This link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_methods.htm) is a list of all HTTP method options you can use. POST is usually used in creating a brand new resource.

This problem is an open issue (marked 182) on the OpenAPI's Github.

I hope this helps!